# Is there a way for an internal module in an ambient declaration to use a type from an external module?

Tags: typescript

In this declaration, I'd like the interface ITest to have a property 'modA' of the type 'ModA' from the external module 'modA':

```
declare module foo {
    interface ITest {
        str: string;
        modA: ModA;
    }
}

declare module "modA" {
    class ModA {
        num: number;
    }
    export = ModA;
}
```

Comment: Starting from TypeScript 0.9, a module is no longer a "type", so what you want to do may not be possible...

Comment: Spent some time on this and concluded moving these into two separate d.ts files is the solution, with "foo" importing "modA".  In my case this approach resulted in writing import statements just to get type information.  Unfortunately these statements also resulted in the mid being added to the define statement!  Submitted an issue: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2111

Answer (score 0):

Use **external** modules **everywhere** and then optimize it with r.js from RequireJS package.